# What is wrong with this optimization problem? I keep getting: ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence

Tags: python, arrays, optimization

I keep getting ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence. How can I get this optimization problem to work?

It seems I am doing something wrong with the dimension of the arrays or with the transpose function

```
# Define inputs as column vectors
ETFs_sigma = np.array([.0467,.0781,.0358,.0618,.0331])
ETFs_sigma.shape = (5,1)

ETFs_mu = np.array([.0157,.0131,.0083,.0163,.0120])
ETFs_mu.shape = (5,1)

ones_vector = np.ones(5)
ones_vector.shape = (5,1)

risk_free = .0002

# Optimization problem
w = np.linspace(0,1)
def objective_function3(w,risk_free,coeff_ra,ETFs_mu,ETFs_sigma):
    w = np.array([w[0], w[1], w[2], w[3], w[4]])
    w.shape = (5,1)
    return - (np.dot(np.transpose(w),ETFs_mu) + (ones_vector-w)*risk_free -1/2*coeff_ra[0]*np.dot(np.transpose(w),ETFs_sigma))

res3 = opt.minimize(objective_function3, (.1,.2,.3,.4,.5), args=(risk_free,coeff_ra,ETFs_mu,ETFs_sigma))
res3
```

I expect an array with 5 inputs for the solution i.e. the weights of this optimal portfolio

Comment: Did you search for ` ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.`?  There are probably a number of SO q&a's that would give you a good start.

Comment: As the error says, you are trying to assign a sequence to an element of the array. Please share a self-contained snipped of the code and the exact error message (with the line number of occurrence). Also, I think you should be defining the shapes for the variables ETFs_sigma and ETFs_mu when you already have values assigned to it.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page. Which line cause the error? When posting a question about code that produces an Exception, always include the complete Traceback - copy and paste it then format it as code.